# Formula of Summation of Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of $2n$ terms of the series: $1^2−3^2+5^2−7^2+9^2−11^2+\cdots$

***Method 1: Sum Notation***
2 versions of answers from different professors is
i)
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (4k-3)^2-\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (4k-1)^2$$

versus

ii)
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} (4k-3)^2-\sum_{k=1}^{n} (4k-1)^2$$
So, which notation is the correct? Do both of them yield the same result? My given answer is $−8n^2$ or $−32n^2$. Most of the answers given from different experts are $−8n^2$ and why? Which one is the answer?

AND
***Method 2***: Merge 2n terms to  n terms, and it is arithmetic series for n terms 
$S_{2n}=1-9\qquad+25-49\qquad  +81-121 +... =-8n^2$

$S_{n}= -8 \qquad\qquad -24 \qquad\qquad -40\qquad+...=\frac{n[2(-8)+(n-1)(-16)]}{2}=-8n^2$

$S_{2n}=-8n^2$

Let's input the value inside, set n=3
There are 3 terms in $S_n$=$S_3$

$S_{n}=S_3=(-8)+(-24)+(-40)=-72$

There are 6 terms in $S_{2n}=S_6$

$S_{2n}=S_6=1^2−3^2+5^2−7^2+9^2−11^2=-72$

$S_{2n}=S_n=-8n^2$
$=S_6=S_3=-8(3)^2=-72$

AND
***Method 3: by factorisation***,
A)
$(1^2-3^2)+(5^2-7^2)+(9^2-11^2)+\cdots$
$=(1-3)(1+3)+(5-7)(5+7)+(9-11)(9+11)+\cdots$
$=(-2)(4+12+20+\cdots$)
$=(-2)(\frac{n[2(4)+(n-1)(8)]}{2})$
$=-8n^2$

B)
$(1^2-3^2)+(5^2-7^2)+(9^2-11^2)+\cdots$
$=(1-3)(1+3)+(5-7)(5+7)+(9-11)(9+11)+\cdots$
$=(-2)(4+12+20+\cdots$)
$=(-2)(4)(1+3+5+\cdots)$
$$=(-2)(4)(\sum_{k=1}^{n} (2k-1))$$
$$=(-8)(\sum_{k=1}^{n} (2k)-\sum_{k=1}^{n} (1))$$
$$=(-8)[2\sum_{k=1}^{n} (k)-\sum_{k=1}^{n} (1)]$$
$$\qquad\qquad given $$$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
So, $(-8)[2\sum_{k=1}^{n} (k)-\sum_{k=1}^{n} (1)]$
$=(-8)[(2)(\frac{n(n+1)}{2})-n]$
$=-8n^2$

, But then, this $-8n^2$ is sum to n terms or sum to 2n terms?

Should I let $f(n)=-8(n)^2$ and then input $2n$ to the $f(n)=-8(n)^2$, where $f(2n)=-8(2n)^2=-32n^2$?
So $-8n^2 or -32n^2$? What do you think?

And $$\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (4k-3)^2-\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (4k-1)^2$$ Is this notation correct for the sum to $2n$ terms?

Comment: They give different results.  Personally I would go for (ii) saying when $n=1$ the first $2n=2$ terms are $1^2-3^2 = -8=-8n^2$ and when $n=2$ the first $2n=4$ terms are $1^2-3^2+5^2-7^2=-32=-8n^2$, and so on for other $n$

Comment: Method 1, i). Those two sums have in total $4n$ terms, not $2n$ terms.

Comment: Ya I agree with Method 1 ii).
$\sum_{k=1}^{n} (4k-3)^2+\sum_{k=1}^{n} -(4k-1)^2$
=     Sum of $a_{n_1}$ + Sum of $a_{n_2}$

Comment: @jjagmath To be clear: you mean that's the incorrect one.

Comment: @jjagmath. Yes. In Method 1 ii) the superscripts  should be $n$, not $2n$.

Comment: My preference is for Method 3 as it resolves into the sum of an arithmetic sequence, which is easy.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete different and general ansatz. It is developed by a application of the [Pascal/Binomial-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_matrix) and its [Neumann series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series). This method does -in the same run- give the same style of formulas for the summation for all other exponents, as far as desired.

---

Consider the (upper) triangular Pascal-matrix (in the following truncated to *5x5* but can easily be extended)
$$ P= \small \begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & 1 & \color{\red} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
 . & 1 & \color{\red} 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
 . & . & \color{\red} 1 & 3 & 6 \\ 
 . & . & . & 1 & 4 \\ 
 . & . & . & . & 1
 \end{bmatrix} \tag 1
$$
and a vector-function $ V(x)=[1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,...]$ of length appropriate to the matrix-multiplication with $P$.

By the dotproduct
$$ V(x) \cdot P = V(x+1) \tag 2 $$
we apply the binomial-theorem on powers of $x$ with the coefficients of a column in $P$, for instance as in the current question, with the third column: $ 1\cdot\color{\red} 1 + x\cdot \color{\red}  2+ x^2 \cdot \color{\red} 1 = (x+1)^2 $.

Next, by taking the power of $2$ of $P$ : $PP= P^2 = P \cdot P$
$$ PP = \small \begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & 2 & \color{\red} 4 & 8 & 16 \\ 
 . & 1 & \color{\red} 4 & 12 & 32 \\ 
 . & . & \color{\red} 1 & 6 & 24 \\ 
 . & . & . & 1 & 8 \\ 
 . & . & . & . & 1
 \end{bmatrix} \tag 3 $$
we have even more
$$ V(x) \cdot PP = V(x+2) \tag 4 $$
for instance $V(3) \cdot PP = V(5)$, and especially by *3*'rd column $3^0\cdot \color{\red} 4 + 3^1\cdot \color{\red} 4 + 3^2 \cdot \color{\red} 1 = 5^2$ and perhaps this already uncovers, where we want to go with this...

---

Next we do a finite sum ***of powers of PP***
$$ V(x) \cdot \bigl( PP^0 - PP^1 + PP^2 \bigr)= V(x+0)-V(x+2)+V(x+4) \tag 5 $$
and again, using the example of $x=3$ we get
$V(3) \cdot \bigl(PP^0 - PP^1 + PP^2 \bigr) = V(3) - V(5) + V(7)$ and in the third colum of the result we find $ 3^2 - 5^2 + 7^2$.

---

Now to make this a shorter general formula for arbitray many summands we introduce the "Neumann"-series of matrices (see wikipedia link above), which is the equivalent of the ***geometric series*** applied to a matrix-argument
$$  PP^0 - PP^1 + PP^2 - \cdots + \cdots \overset{\mathfrak R}= (I + PP)^{-1} = A  \tag 6$$
The symbol $\mathfrak R$ indicates that this has to be understood as a "regularization" form; for instance the W|A-online software gives for the input $1^2-3^2+5^2-7^2 + ...$ the coefficients which I also show in the following matrix-result by clauses "*Abel regularization*" and "*Borel-regularization*".

The matrix-calculation of the inversion formula in the rhs can easily be done in rational numbers only:
$$ A= \small \begin{bmatrix} 
 1/2 & -1/2 & \color{\red} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 . & 1/2 & \color{\red} {-1} & 0 & 4 \\ 
 . & . & \color{\red} {1/2} & -3/2 & 0 \\ 
 . & . & . & 1/2 & -2 \\ 
 . & . & . & . & 1/2
 \end{bmatrix} \tag 7
$$

With this we can now write
$$ V(x) \cdot A = V(x) - V(x+2) + V(x+4) - \cdots + \cdots \tag 8 $$
and of course the telescoping sum
$$ \begin{array}{} \bigl( V(x) - V(x+4) \bigr) \cdot A &=& \bigl( V(x) - V(x+2) + V(x+4) - \cdots + \cdots \bigr) \\
&-& \bigl(V(x+4) - V(x+6) + V(x+8) \cdots \bigr) \\
&=& V(x) - V(x+2) \end{array} \tag 9 $$

Again for example $x=3$, we get $ (V(3)-V(7)) \cdot A=V(3)-V(5)$ and by the third column of $A$ we get $$ (1-1)\cdot \color{\red} 0 + (3-7) \cdot \color{\red} {-1} + (3^2-7^2) \cdot \color{\red} {\frac12} = +4-20 = -16 = 3^2-5^2 \tag {10}$$

---

I think it is easily recognizable how to apply this to the general cases, not only for the alternating sums-of-squares of arguments-in-steps-of *2* but to all other exponents as well. It gives just generalization of the ["Faulhaber"-equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) for the current type of alternating series.

<sub>*More of this at my [math-homepage](https://go.helms-net.de/math/) the entry "[summing of like powers](https://go.helms-net.de/math/binomial_new/04_3_SummingOfLikePowers.pdf)"*</sub>

Comment: *For the ones who like this ansatz at all (like me) one could google for "Pascalmatrix plus one" and similar terms and find essays about this sometimes written in a easy understandable exploratory style.*

Comment: wtf, that's crazy, thanks. @Gottfried Helms